# Pass variable throught the methods doesn't work in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple form and i using Vue.js with Firebase (with package [vue-firestore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-firestore)) and i have a methods to register the user in firebase, change the `displayName` value and logout the current user and after this i register some fields in a [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), but i need to save the **uid** of the user created to save in the firestore, but i can access the value of the variable in the method `createProvider`

my vuejs component:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { db } from "../firebase";
import "firebase/auth";

export default {
  data: () => ({
    // item fields
    nameProvider:"",
    enderecoProvider:"",
    numeroProvider:"",
    cityProvider: "",
    distritoProvider: "",
    paisProvider:"",
    complementoProvider: "",
    telefoneProvider: "",
    nomeContatoProvider: "",
    emailProvider: "",
    passwordProvider: "",
    userId: "",
    userIdTemp: "",
  }),

   firestore() {
    return {
      users: db.collection("users"),
    };
  },

  methods: {
    signUp() {
      var that = this;
       firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.emailProvider, this.passwordProvider)
        .then((user) => {
     //  HERE I CREATE THE USER USING FIREBASE AUTH AND I'M TRYNG TO GET THE UID FROM THIS AND STORE IN THE this.userId
           
          this.userId = user.user.uid;
          this.authState(); // the method to 
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("ERRO", error);
        });
    },
     authState() {
      var that = this;
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            user.updateProfile({
                displayName: "2",
              });
                firebase.auth().signOut().then(() =>{
                  that.$swal({
                      icon: "success",
                      title: "Fornecedor criado com sucesso",
                      text: "Por motivos de segurança refaça seu login"
                    }).then((result) => {
                      if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        that.$router.replace('/');
                        location.reload();
                      }
                    })
                })
           console.log(user);
          } else {
            // No user is signed in.
          }
        });
    },

// this method is in button to register in form, i need to get the userId in signIn method to
    createProvider() {
      if (this.$refs.providerForm.validate()) {
         this.signUp();
                 this.$firestore.users.add({
                      nome: this.nameProvider,
                      telefone: this.telefoneProvider,
                      email: this.emailProvider,
                      endereco: this.enderecoProvider,
                      numero: this.numeroProvider,
                      cidade: this.cityProvider,
                      distrito: this.distritoProvider,
                      pais: this.paisProvider,
                      complemento: this.complementoProvider,
                      nomeContato: this.nomeContatoProvider,
                      nivel: "2",
                      uid: this.userId, // i need to save in the method signUp() but i can get the value
                  });
      }
    },
  },
};
```

I need to pass the this.userId value saved in signUp() method to the createProvider() and register in firestore.

Comment: Add the code:  alert(JSON.stringify(user) after the .then()     This will show you the contents of the user variable, from there, you should be able to figure out the proper variable name for the user id (if the method returned it)

Comment: @Sparky how can i do it?

Comment: How is `createProvider` called? What value do you see for `this.userId` in `createProvider`?

Comment: @tony19 the createProvider is a click button event

Comment: And what do u see for `console.log(this.userId)` in that function?

Comment: @tony19 the method work ok, but i can pass the variable to the another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **.bind(this)** in your code where you want to access **this.** and you are not able to do that. or assign **this** first to some variable and inside that recall function you can use that variable

```
signUp() {
      var selfVar = this;
       firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.emailProvider, this.passwordProvider)       
     .then((user) => {
     //  HERE I CREATE THE USER USING FIREBASE AUTH AND I'M TRYNG TO GET THE UID FROM THIS AND STORE IN THE this.userId
           
          selfVar.userId = user.user.uid;
          selfVar.authState(); // the method to 
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("ERRO", error);
        });
    }
```

or use async function instead directly to get user info if auth call will succeed

```
async signUp() 
{ 
    const user = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.emailProvider,this.passwordProvider); 
    if(user){
     console.log(user);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I did understand, how can i pass the this.userId to the another method??

Comment: I tried your code and the error appears `error  'bind' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: Did you try this?

.then(user => (this.userId = user.user.id));

Comment: Also, I have updated the .bind position. hope it will work now.

Else assign 'this' to some variable first outside the function and use that variable instead..

Like

`var selfVar = this;`

and in function

`selfVar.userId`

Comment: the error now is `.bind is not a function`
`

Comment: @MatheusBarem
Can you check this?

`async signUp() {
const user = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.emailProvider, this.passwordProvider)
}`

Comment: but the variable is not in the another method

Comment: try to use `this.$firestore.users.add` function call into the `".then"` part of the  `"firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword"` . Beause it's the matter of the time. May be when `this.$firestore.users.add` is called there is no user data response from `"firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword"` .